# Python make each lock in multithread

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I'm considering how to make several locks for each thread.

I have 3 threads right now.

A : main thread(data sending)
B : data receiving thread
C : data sending every 2 sec thread

I don't want to stop B(receiving thread) except sending time.
How can I use Lock between A,B   and between A,C easily!!...

```
class A:
    def __init__():
        self._A_B_lock = RLock()
        self._A_C_lock = RLock()
        self._B = threading.Thread(target=B_receiving_thread, args=(self._A_B_lock,) ... ).start()
        self._C = threading.Thread(target=C_sending_2sec_thread, args=(self._A_C_lock,) ... ).start()

    def sending():
        with A_B_lock:
            sending_data()

    def B_receiving_thread(self,A_B_lock):
        while(1):
            with A_B_lock:
                receiving_data()
            #do something

    def C_sending_2sec_thread(self,A_C_lock):
        while(1):
            with A_C_lock:
                self.sending()

    # actually I want to make decorator with A_C_lock, I have so many functions.
    def so_many_functions():
        with self.A_C_lock:
            #do important thing
```

This code doesn’t work..

Answer (score 0):

A decorator is a good idea. You could use this

```
def decorator(*locks):
    def _decorator(func):
        def inner_function(*args, **kwargs):
            for lock in locks:
                lock.acquire()
            value = func(*args, **kwargs)
            for lock in locks:
                lock.release()
            return value
        return inner_function
    return _decorator
```

And then you decorate each function, and pass as parameter all the locks that that function will need to make his job without interfeering others. Like this,

```
lock1 = threading.Lock()
lock2 = threading.Lock()

@decorator(lock1, lock2)
def f1(word):
    for char in word:
        print(char)
    '''DO STUFF'''


@decorator(lock1, lock2)
def f2(word):
    for char in word:
        print(char)
    '''
    DO STUFF
    '''


t1 = threading.Thread(target=f1, args=('Hello ',))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=f2, args=('world',))
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Thats just a dummy example, but you can easily apply it to your code. Good thing about it, is that you can easily choose wich locks you want to use for each different function.

Hope it helps